# What does it mean, "sniff the green tweed of England"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Michael Pearson says to Matthew about a crowded place to store his weed:

> Michael: The problem with land in this country is there's not much of
>   it... and there's public access even when it's supposed to be private.
>   And the public have rights: dog walkers......footpaths, right to roam,
>   bimblers, ramblers, badger lovers...and any other busy c_nt with
>   enough time on his hands to **sniff the green tweed of England**.

What does it mean, "sniff the green tweed of England"?

I have a feeling that it doesn't mean what it means.

I find these lines in **The Gentlemen 2019**

Comment: Have you ever seen a picture of, or visited England, and looked at the rural landscape? Did you notice anything green about it?

Comment: Does it mean green grass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Tweed' here is a [metaphor](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/metaphor/). Tweed is a rough cloth made from wool, often worn historically on country estates:

> Tweed needed to provide camouflage for hunting and deer stalking.  As
>   such, the colours were derived from the land itself, and even the
>   brightest were designed to blend in with the [...] terrain.

It could also be that the green vegetation of the English landscape is being compared to the wool fibres providing the texture of tweed cloth.

[Tweed Guide](https://www.gentlemansgazette.com/tweed-guide-harris-history-styles-patterns/)

Comment: You’re not quite clear about this in your answer, but specifically tweed is a metaphor for the wealthy, estate-owning upper class (often nobility, though more so in days of yore). Sniffing the green tweed of English (where tweed is substituting for grass) is essentially rambling on private land hoping to catch a glimpse of what the rich are doing – snobbish paparazzi-like fawning on ‘the other other half’.